# Зачем нужен maven?

Tags: java, maven, сборка

Здравствуйте, очень хотелось бы узнать, много пересмотрел и перечитал, но не могу понять. Зачем нужен Maven, если есть IDE - Eclipse, Netbeans и т.д.? В чем его преимущество по сборкам, если и IDE справляются?

Comment: IDE справляются, если у вас маленький карманный проект. Как только вам захочется подключить внешних зависимостей, настроить автотестирование, разделить сборки на тестовую/промышленную и т.д. - вот тут то просветление и придет. Если проводить аналогию, то это как разница между сборкой коробочек на конвеере тётей Клавой  и сборкой мерседеса на роботизированной линии.

Comment: Если справляются, значит вам он пока не нужен. Основное преимущество `maven` управление зависимостями

Comment: И да, смотрите сразу на `gradle`, он модный, молодёжный

Comment: Ну да)и Grovy впридачу осваивать

Comment: @rjhdby, или ant? Классическая проблема A vs B vs C.

Comment: @vp_arth да хоть `make`. С гредлом будет проще к андроиду переходить, если что. Да и в целом, ну объективно, gradle во многом получше будет. Вообще холивор конечно, так что предлагаю не развивать :)

Comment: StackOverflow? В чем суть? Вопрос не связан с практикой и относится скорее к философии чем к программированию. Если можно справиться без инструмента, то, значит, он и не нужен. По крайней мере пока.

Comment: @rjhdby и зачем gradle? тормознутый и сложный в освоении. Да у него есть гибкость, но она в большинстве проектов просто не нужна.

Comment: Maven для Java это что-то вроде Сomposer для PHP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не совсем корректный вопрос, нельзя сравнивать Maven и среды разработки. C Maven можно работать и без сред разработки. Зачем нужен? Для управления зависимостями, для сборки проектов, и для кучи всего остального полезного. К примеру, ты пишешь большой проект и используешь в нем много технологий, к примеру, Hibernate, JUnit. Возникает вопрос как подключить все библиотеки? Ответ прост - просто прописать зависимости в pom.xml, а maven их скачает за тебя. Затем возможна такая ситуация, ты хочешь показать проект другу, отправляешь ему, но вот проблема, если это не проект Maven, то твоему другу придется скачивать библиотеки, чтобы проект заработал, а так за него это сделает Maven.С ростом твоих проектов - ты сам оценишь достоинства Maven. 
IDE справляются -  а если нет IDE на твоем компьютере?Что будешь делать? На помощь приходит Maven, он кроссплатформенный и для работы с ним достаточно командной строки.

Comment: Дополню основной ответ. IDE используют системы сборок, Ant, Maven, Gradle

Comment: По-моему теоретизировать о ситуациях "когда на твоём компьютере нет IDE", это примерно как теоретизировать о ситуациях, когда у тебя в квартире нет электричества.

Answer (score 10):

IDE умеет собирать проект, но каждая делает это по разному - использует разную версию java, кодировку, структуру проекта, внешние библиотеки находятся в разных местах и могут иметь разную версию.

Maven и другие системы сборки используются для унификации этого процесса. Они имеют ряд достоинств:

- с их помощью указываются версии библиотек, и что не маловажно, система знает откуда их брать.
- имеет устоявшуюся структуру проекта, это позволяет избежать путаницы и легче найти то что нужно.
- имеет определенный набор шагов - компиляция, тестирование, упаковка и тд.
- возможность кастомизации процесса сборки - добавления дополнительных шагов
- сборка не зависит от IDE, операционной системы и пр, т.к. можно указать версию компилятора, кодировку и пр.